# Print random numbers in a range

Tags: c#, random, range

I have got this homework assignment and I have come with a solution which works, but I do not understand why when entering range from [0 to 1] the Random() function prints only zeroes. When I ad 1 to the max argument it works //rnd.Next(min, max + 1);, but why only zeroes when it is left like this: rnd.Next(min, max);

```
static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter integer n: ");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Please enter min integer: ");
        int min = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Please enter max integer: ");
        int max = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(rnd.Next(min, max+1));
        }
    }
```

Comment: How many integers are there between 0 and 1?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `Random.Next`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Random.Next` produces a number in the range `[min, max)` -- that means `min` is a possible result, but `max` is not. The only integer in the range `[0, 1)` is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

[It is part of the language definition.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The maximum value is exclusive, not inclusive, so if you want `max` to be included, you must add 1 to it.